# Pandas .loc[] side effect changes bools to floats

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'b':[False,True,False,True,False]})

# changes all False values to NaN
df.loc[~df['b'], 'b'] = np.nan

print(df.to_dict())
# {'b': {0: nan, 1: 1.0, 2: nan, 3: 1.0, 4: nan}}
```

Since loc only changes specific values in the column, I would expect something like `{'b': {0: nan, 1: True, 2: nan, 3: True, 4: nan}}`, which is not the case. Why does .loc change booleans to floats, and what's a good workaround for this?

Comment: `.loc` is not changing the type; it's your inclusion of the value of `np.NaN`. A column in a `DataFrame` must all have data of the the same type. There is no `bool` representation of `NaN`, so pandas decides that since `np.NaN`, `False=0` and `True=1` can all be represented as a `float` that the entire column becomes a float column.

Answer (score 6):

The type `bool` in Python and NumPy and Pandas can only be True or False.  It cannot be NaN.  So when you introduce a NaN value to a `bool` (or `int`) series, it becomes `float` instead.

One alternative is to use a second `bool` column to indicate NaN values.  Another is to use a NumPy "masked array."  A third might be to change the column type to `i1` and use `-1` to indicate NaN.

Answer (score 4):

If you change the `dtype` to `np.object` so it supports mixed `dtypes` and explicitly test for `False` then this works:

```
In[200]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'b':[False,True,False,True,False]})
df['b'] = df['b'].astype(np.object)
# changes all False values to NaN
df.loc[df['b']==False, 'b'] = np.nan
df

Out[200]: 
      b
0   NaN
1  True
2   NaN
3  True
4   NaN
```

If you tried to do `df.loc[~df['b'],'b']=np.nan` then this raises the error:

```
KeyError: '[-1 -2 -1 -2 -1] not in index'
```

if you print the type then this shows that the values really are `float` and `bool`:

```
print(type(df['b'].iloc[0]))
print(type(df['b'].iloc[1]))
<class 'float'>
<class 'bool'>
```

As noted in the other answers, `bool` cannot represent `NaN`, only `float` dtype can, so `pandas` is upconverting the `dtype` of the `Series` to the most compatible type which in this case is `float`. If you set the `dtype` to `np.object` then this allows a heterogenous `dtype` so there is no `dtype` conversion.

**UPDATE**

As noted in the comments, using mixed dtypes will severely impact performance and storage, if you must have mixed types then this is the only way this will work. Otherwise you could have an additional column to just mark the rows that are `NaN` as suggested.

Comment: You should note that `dtype=object` severely impacts performance and memory usage for large arrays.  This solution uses 8x the memory, and is more than 8x slower than storing a simple three-valued `i1` dtype.

Comment: @johnzwink that's a good valid point, I'm not a fan of mixed types, you lose performance and vectorised operations. I'll update the answer when I get back.

Answer (score 3):

In the beginning the type of column "b" was `bool`, as all entries were `bool`s. Then you changed some entries, so the type changed to the next in line that has all the values. In this case this is `float`, since neither `bool`, nor `int` (of which `bool` inherits) have a NaN value, but `float` does.

If you for example set `df.loc[~df['b'], 'b'] = "False"`, this has to escalate further up, until it hits `object`. All types inherit from `object` in Python 3, so a column of `objects` can contain any object.

In other words, all entries in a pandas column have to be of the same type. The type is dynamically adjusted to the closest type that all objects in it share. In your case that is `float`.